# How to set the recoveryenabled to NO in bcdedit?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcdedit

How to set the recoveryenabled to NO in bcdedit on Windows 7 32 bits????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this command:

```
bcdedit /set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

Similar is

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

They can be the same if you are booted into the default load, so default would equal current.

For more information, the relevant Google search is "disable Windows Error Recovery" (minus the quotes).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794974(v=winembedded.1001).aspx

Comment: I am assuming that you are trying to disable Windows Error Recovery when you say "recoveryenabled set to no".

Comment: It didnt work, I queryed the dcbedit values and it returned "recoveryenabled Yes", on the tail there was "bootstatuspolicy IgnoreAllFailures"

Comment: @Diogo_Rocha Sorry, I misunderstood: do this one instead: bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No

Comment: Dear @KCotreau: please see the question EDIT picture. does this command works for that GUI recovery too? windows 8.1 with latest windows updates of Step 6, 2015 causing that.

Comment: @KCotreau: please reply.